# Problem with nginx location and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have a rule in my nginx.conf that does not work and I have no idea why. According to the documentation it should work. Part of the config looks like this.

The first rule on port 8100 works and redirects the call **http://example.com/api/domains** to **https://localhost:8181/oan/resources/domains**

```
# Working
server {
    listen                  8100 default_server;
    server_name             example.com;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host      $http_host;
    root                    /var/www/html/example;

    location /api {
       proxy_pass https://localhost:8181/oan/resources; break;
    }

    # For ReactJS to handle routes
    location / {
       if (!-e $request_filename) {
          rewrite ^(.*)$ / break;
       }
    }
}

# Not working
server {
    listen                  8200;
    server_name             api.example.com;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host      $http_host;

    location / {
       proxy_pass https://localhost:8181/oan/resources; break;
    }
}
```

The last call to port 8200: **http://api.example.com:8200/domains** SHOULD redirect to: **https://localhost:8181/oan/resources/domains** but does NOT do that.

What is wrong with this config and how can I get the last rule on port 8200 do the correct stuff, always redirect to **https://localhost:8181/oan/resources/$uri**

Comment: Try: `proxy_pass https://localhost:8181/oan/resources/;`

Comment: Great. That worked like a charm !!!

Answer (score 6):

When you use `proxy_pass` with an *optional URI* within a *prefix* location block, Nginx will transform the requested URI by performing a straight text substitution.

In your case, the prefix location value is `/` and the optional URI value is `/oan/resources`. So a requested URI of `/foo` will be transformed into `/oan/resourcesfoo`.

For correct operation, both values should end with `/` or neither end with `/`.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:8181/oan/resources/;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: We had a problem of infinite redirects when using proxy_pass in combination with `set`. Removing the matching path in the variable and proxy_pass and just leaving the path in the location and also removing the the trailing `/` for everything resolved the problem. Your answer helped finding this, thanks

Comment: For anybody interested it looks something like this:
    location /_plugin/kibana {
        set $kibana kibana-url.com;
        proxy_pass $kibana;
    }